# Including jQuery in a public project - License?

Tags: jquery, licensing

When I upload a copy of jQuery to one of my github repos, what shall I do to get the licensing right?

jQuery is MIT licensed, so I am *"free to use any jQuery project in any other project (even commercial projects) as long as the copyright header is left intact"*. However, the minimal, production versions just contain a very limited header.

Is it OK to just upload the .js file or do I have to add a LICENSE file containing the copyright and the MIT license?

I guess this is not a big issue but I want to do things right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a layer, but to me all of MIT licenses (yes, there are at least two of them – essentially the same, but still different) quite clearly oblige you to distribute full text of license along with code:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

But jQuery Foundation itself by some reason does not follow this paragraph – [code available to download](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) on official site does not include neither full text of license, nor ever a direct link to text.

I do not use jQuery, but if I were do it, I probably either just would not worry about it or would include full text of license in `jquery.js` itself.

I would not recommend you to use a file with text of license when the only place where you can upload is a project root, since you can easily mislead people by storing a `LICENSE.MIT` file in root along with, for instance, `COPYING.AGPL3` – one could groundlessly think, that both licenses applies to your whole project, which is not true, as far I understand you.